# Retirar espaços em branco de uma string e junta-la

Tags: java, string

Tenho uma string de uma Expressão Lógica

Ex:

```
((T ∨ F → T) ∧ (T → F)) → (∼F → T)
```

Preciso retirar os espaços em branco da string e junta-las tendo como resultado:

```
((T∨F→T)∧(T→F))→(∼F→T)
```

Como consigo fazer isso no Java? Tentei usar o `replaceAll("\\s","");` porém não obtive êxito.

Comment: Utilize `string.replaceAll(" ", "");` ou `string.replaceAll("\\s", "");`

Comment: Você tem certeza que são espaços mesmo?

Comment: Strings são imutáveis em Java, então o método gerará uma nova variável. Você está armazenando essa nova variável?

Comment: Acabou dando certo, acredito que foi algum erro meu na hora da criação do método, funcionou sim com o string.replaceAll("\\s", ""); muito obrigado!